# Why don't my written files not save the inputted text in Python?

Tags: python, file-writing

I'm making a chatbot and the first thing the user does if the UserName.txt file isn't there is input their name and likes, but the inputted text doesn't save. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried removing the UserLike function to see if that makes a difference, but it doesn't seem to work

```
def NameSay():

    UserName = input(": ")
    UserNameFile = open("UserName.txt", "w+")
    UserNameFile.write(UserName)
    print("So your name is "+ UserName + ", right?")
    NameConfirm = input(": ")

    if 'yes' in NameConfirm or 'Yes' in NameConfirm or 'right' in NameConfirm or 'Right' in NameConfirm or 'ya' in NameConfirm or 'Ya' in NameConfirm or 'yeah' in NameConfirm or 'Yeah' in NameConfirm:
        print("Good to meet you, " + UserName + ". I'm Ene, your virtual assistant, friend, coworker, whatever you need me to be!")
        print("Now, why don't you tell me a bit about yourself? What you like and all of that.")
        UserLike = input(": ")
        UserLikesFile = open("UserLikes.txt", "w")
        UserLikesFile.write(UserLike)
        print("Thank you! This is very interesting info.")

    if NameConfirm in ['no', 'No']:
        print("Oh? Then tell me what your name is.")
        NameSay()

if os.path.isfile('UserName.txt') == True:
    f = open("UserName.txt", "r")
    file_contents = f.read()
    welcomes = ["Welcome back, " + file_contents, "Hey-o! Good to see you again, " + file_contents]
    print("\n" + welcomes[random.randint(0,1)])
    Main_Menu()

if os.path.isfile('UserName.txt') == False:
    print("\nHey-o! I don't think we've met before! What\'s your name?")
    NameSay()
```

The text should save into the written files, but the files end up being blank.

Comment: Where are you closing your files? What happens if you don't do that can be somewhat unpredictable.

Comment: You `open` the file, but never close or flush it, so it never finishes writing. Consider using the context manager `with open(` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be on the safe side, you can flush the output to the file right after the write function.

```
UserNameFile.flush()
```

Also, don't forget to close the the file

```
UserNameFile.close()
```

Comment: The flush probably won't be needed if he actually closes the file. Or just use a context: `with open() as f:`

Answer (score 1):

I've have just ran this and the data did save so I'm not too sure what you are on about. However I can see you haven't closed the files after using them as you should.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two problem I think:

1- When you open a file, you should close or flush that file to be able to read that file. I used `with` statement for file management.

2- You are calling `NameSay()` recursively and if a person enter his username wrong for 10 times, your function call stack should save all of them. So, I edited your last line of code that doesn't call the function recursively and edited the `NameSay` function to return `True` or `False` for determine that was it successful or not

```py
def NameSay():

    UserName = input(": ")
    with open("UserName.txt", "w+") as UserNameFile:
        UserNameFile.write(UserName)
    print("So your name is "+ UserName + ", right?")
    NameConfirm = input(": ")

    if 'yes' in NameConfirm or 'Yes' in NameConfirm or 'right' in NameConfirm or 'Right' in NameConfirm or 'ya' in NameConfirm or 'Ya' in NameConfirm or 'yeah' in NameConfirm or 'Yeah' in NameConfirm:
        print("Good to meet you, " + UserName + ". I'm Ene, your virtual assistant, friend, coworker, whatever you need me to be!")
        print("Now, why don't you tell me a bit about yourself? What you like and all of that.")
        UserLike = input(": ")
        with open("UserLikes.txt", "w") as UserLikesFile:
            UserLikesFile.write(UserLike)
        print("Thank you! This is very interesting info.")
        return True

    if NameConfirm in ['no', 'No']:
        print("Oh? Then tell me what your name is.")
        return False

if os.path.isfile('UserName.txt') == True:
    f = open("UserName.txt", "r")
    file_contents = f.read()
    welcomes = ["Welcome back, " + file_contents, "Hey-o! Good to see you again, " + file_contents]
    print("\n" + welcomes[random.randint(0,1)])
    Main_Menu()

if os.path.isfile('UserName.txt') == False:
    print("\nHey-o! I don't think we've met before! What\'s your name?")
    while(not NameSay())
        continue
```